# Video playback in qml using vlc linux

Tags: qt5, media-player, vlc, qmediaplayer, vlc-qt

How to link the video playback in qml application to use vlc library instead of gstreamer library.
Because I get an error "gstreamer encountered general stream error"

Comment: I think that QtMultimedia has only GStreamer plugins.

Comment: Yes but I am gettings errors on the gstreamer so i wanted to go to libVLC

Comment: export GST_DEBUG=*:5 and see what's the general stream error is all about first.